# Is there a linux command to block until a process exits?

Tags: linux, bash, csh

It's just what the question asks.  Also, all I have is the PID, and the shell I am running the command from is not necessarily the shell that initially invoked the process.  Any ideas?

Comment: I know it isn't kosher to ask a question about the question, but... how do you know the PID of a process that hasn't been created?  PIDs can be rather random.  Sure, in practice they are assigned linearly but you don't know how many processes will start between time `A` and `B` or if the PID counter will wrap.

Comment: @TomMD maybe he uses `pidof` to find the PID of the process at runtime, or maybe something else. There are a hundred different ways he could have the PID of a process, while not hard-coding it in the shell script ;)

Comment: @TomMD I know the PID because I know the process name, and I can use the ps command to get the PID.

Comment: @TomMD: I don't think there's any problem with asking questions about questions.

Comment: @all - oops.  Somehow I completely misread the question as "how to block until a process _exists_" and under that question you can probably better understand my confusion :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ps -p $PID >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done
```

or

```
while ps -p $PID >/dev/null 2>&1; do :; done
```

Comment: That's the best answer that I've seen. I wonder why bash's built-in version of wait only works when it is a child process of the current shell.

Comment: @B Johnson: Because it takes a job ID which is only valid in the current shell instead of taking a PID. There are probably other reasons internal to the way job control works.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a very neat way to do it, but you may continuously issue `kill(2)` system calls to the specified pid, putting zero as a signal. The first time `kill` doesn't succeed by setting `errno` to `ESRCH`, you may conclude that the process has exited.

Comment: kill -0 ${PID} is the preferred way. It is portable and fast since it uses just one simple syscall.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the dir /proc/PID exists. It seems cleaner than sending multiple signals